# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while launching the android application in libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

guys when am trying to run the android application via the desktop application this runtime error is popping up again and again. The desktop app works absolutely fine but when i try to run via the android app, it gives the `noclassdeffounderror` for the classes which are there in the desktop application ! 
its been four five hours ! what the hell is wrong with it ? what can be the possible issues with it ?

please suggestions! PS am not using ADT 17 ver. Help guys! thanks!

Comment: hey i am having the same problem. you got the solution?

Comment: @shiladitya check my answer, it may help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a NoClassDefFoundError while launching Android LibGDX Project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926414/how-do-i-fix-a-noclassdeffounderror-while-launching-android-libgdx-project)

Answer (score 0):

Right Click your Android project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export Check the libraries you are using (Gdx.jar for example).

Answer (score 0):

Right Click your Android project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Exports
**Export all your jars** that you are using **and your desktop project** with android project as shown in image and this would let your applicaion run on android.

Answer (score 0):

if every thing is linked well... (using Java Build Path and Order and Export...) and still having problem running project on android check if JRE is set to 1.6.

Change the JRE from the main Java Project from 1.7 to 1.6 and try to run it on android.

Eclipse-> main-java-project--> Expand the directory--> Right click on JRE System library--> Check "Execution environment" --> select JavaES 1.6 jre6-> Click Ok