# How do I fix a NoClassDefFoundError while launching Android LibGDX Project?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am currently learning the [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) game engine (version 1.9.4) and I keep running into a compiling error when trying to run my android version of my project. I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027859/libgdx-myfirsttriangle-example-crashes-on-startup) article and followed the solution that was listed on that question but the same issues keep occurring [log.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fim7wfj7o8hx5p/log.txt?dl=0).

I tried adding the core file directly to the build path like so but still the same issue.[image]

Is there something I'm not understanding about the error message? If so what is it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show me Libraries and Order and Export Tab ?

Comment: With the exception of the core file being there and external dependencies checked everything was default https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9go6cymfzjhev2/Screenshot%20%2811%29.png?dl=0

Comment: select two unchecked library and show me Libraries Jars ?

Comment: I assume you meant to click over to the libraries tab, hard to understand that last statement https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3y7monhv8y7ith/Screenshot%20%2812%29.png?dl=0

Comment: two of library in Order and Export are unselected. select them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click your Android project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Exports Export all your jars that you are using.

still having problem running project on android check if JRE is set to 1.6.

Change the JRE from the main Java Project from 1.7 to 1.6 and try to run it on android.

Eclipse-> main-java-project--> Expand the directory--> Right click on JRE System library--> Check "Execution environment" --> select JavaES 1.6 jre6-> Click Ok

Comment: I just realized I am using LibGDX version 1.9.4 if that helps at all

Comment: eclipse is deprecated by android so leave it and start using IntellijIDEA or Android Studio with gradle support. Configuration in these IDE is far easy and handy.

Comment: Clean the project using the command 'gradlew clean' in the project directory? (I apologies, I don't use gradlew directly, I let Eclipse handle compile stuff).

Comment: Are you sure all library are checked in Order and Export ?

Comment: Changing the Java environment variable to 1.6 worked. Question is why?