# Using your own *.jars in libgdx 1.9.6 (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: gradle, libgdx

Having trouble getting a android compile of a libgdx project to see classes in a .jar file of mine.

From reading around it seems(?) all I should have to do is put them in the /libs directory and ensure the gradle build file has been set to pick them up.
This doesn't seem to be working for me.

See screenshot of mysetup:
[image]

Notes;

- SSS.jar is file containing my classes
- I have configured everything to use Java 1.7 (this needs to be done each gradle refresh, as gradle insists on setting it to 1.8 for some reason)
- Android 4.4 for export,  the device testing uses 6.0
- I have refreshed/cleaned/built more times then I can count ;)
- Desktop compile of the project works fine

The error I get when running as android application is as follows;

```
04-29 19:58:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(9306): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.darkflame.client.semantic.SSSIndex$1
04-29 19:58:10.462: E/AndroidRuntime(9306):     at com.darkflame.client.semantic.SSSIndex.<clinit>(SSSIndex.java:504)
....(can post more if needed, but I think thats the relevant bit)
```

(I also tried exporting a .apk and looking inside with 7zip to try to see if the SSS.jar was exported, but to be honest I don't know what I am looking at. How would I tell ?)

Any pointers on how this setup should work would be appreciated.

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/41926589/3445320

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing it all down to 1.6JRE and I am already exporting absolutely everything (see screenshot). Unfortunately neither made a difference.